# Get currentPositionTimecode from a video file .wmv using WMPLib

Tags: c#, windows-media-player

I would like to extract the first timecode from a .wmv file. Currently i'm using this piece of code :

```
        var wmp = new WindowsMediaPlayer();
        wmp.newMedia(filename);
        WMPLib.IWMPControls3 controls = (WMPLib.IWMPControls3)wmp.controls;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        Console.WriteLine(controls.currentPosition);
        Console.WriteLine(controls.currentPositionTimecode);
```

The output is always 0 and [00000]00:00:00.00 and I don't know what am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found how to do it :

```
using WMPLib;

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private string _Timecode;
     WindowsMediaPlayerClass _Wmp =  new WindowsMediaPlayerClass{volume = 0};
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Wmp.MediaChange += WmpOnMediaChange;
    }

    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(_Timecode);
    }

    private void FrameworkElement_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        const string filename = @"C:\Users\Public\Videos\Toto.wmv";
        _Wmp.URL = filename;
    }

    private void WmpOnMediaChange(object item)
    {
        _Wmp.MediaChange -= WmpOnMediaChange;
        _Wmp.controls.pause();
        _Wmp.controls.currentPosition = 0 ;
        _Timecode = ((IWMPControls3) _Wmp.controls).currentPositionTimecode;
        _Wmp.close();
        _Wmp = null;
    }
}
```